# How to edit sources.list as root under Debian 9?

Tags: debian, software-installation, root

So I just installed Debian 9.0.0 on my PC and now I can't download packages with the Synaptic packet manager as the sources.list file under `/etc/apt/` has only the DVD set.

All other lines are commented out, with this text above the 2 lines I'd like to take back in:

```
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
```

This is probably due to the fact that I wasn't connected to the Internet while installing Debian using the DVD.

Also apparently the DVD isn't detected under Debian as under `/media/` it only says `cdrom` and `cdrom0` no matter if I insert the DVD or not with both being empty. -> Not sure if that is a separate issue?

I cannot edit the sources.list file by just opening it with the texteditor as it's write-protected.
I thought about installing leafpad from here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/leafpad/download and I'm not sure if that would help.

To me it seems that the most straight-forward way would be to open the texteditor as root, comment out the DVD sources and take the 2 security.debian.org sources back in. However I'm not sure how to do that.

I tried `sudo gedit` which gets me this (I translated the part after `Unable to init server:`):

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Connection failed:connection buildup denied

(gedit:1297): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `sudo` working, you should use `sudoedit`:

```
SUDO_EDITOR="gedit -w" sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` to edit the file using a simple text editor such as nano or kate

`sudo kate /etc/apt/sources.list`

or if that doesn't work: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

You should be able to then uncomment what you need and save.
This link will help with default lists: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList